# Unity Project Will Not Load after crash, but other projects still work

Tags: c#, macos, debugging, unity-game-engine, crash

I have a very large project in Unity, and it will not open no matter what I try. I have found that my other projects all work, thus the problem exists solely on this one. I need to recover it as soon as possible, for I am submitting it to a competition. I am currently on Unity Version : 5.3.5f, which is currently the newest version. The project is over 10 gigabytes. I am using a mac on version OSX ElCapitan 10.11.4. Is there a way to restore my project?

Comment: what, in the name of goodness, is over 10 gb ??

Comment: what are you not using 10.11.5 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the 'Library' folder of your project and reopen project using unity.

Comment: You're damn right, Library contains all the cached files. Remove it, and Unity will start by rebuild the project (and skip that f*** cached scripts/files/asset file that was ruining everything) .